# Subtracting two 4x4 Matrices - is this possible?

Tags: math, opengl, matrix

I have two 4x4 OPENGL Matrices -

- 1st matrix holds rotation and position of an object at frame 0.
- 2nd matrix holds rotation and position of an object at frame X;

I want to retrieve a movement offset of an object between frame 0 and X,
is this enough ( possible ) if I just subtract both?

```
CMatrix4x4 offsetMatrix = matrixAtFrameX - matrixAtFrame0;
```

What I am doing is exporting per frame Bone transformation matrix where this matrix is an offset of the transformation between frame 0 of the animation and frame X.

- Can I subtract both matrices ?
- What are the results ?

Comment: You can, but it won't be meaningful. See answer by @AndreasBrinck for the correct way to retrieve relative information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to multiply the matrix at frame x with the inverse of the matrix at frame 0.

```
matrixOffset = inverse(matrixAtFrame0) * matrixAtFrameX
```

This will give you the relative transformation and rotation between the frames.

Comment: Sorry, i believe order is the 'thing' here - should i go with:

INVERSE(MatrixAtFrame0) * MatrixAtFrameX

or

MatrixAtFrameX * INVERSE(MatrixAtFrame0)

?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming standard OpenGL matrices and that you want the matrix that takes you from 0 to X you should go with the answer as it is presented.